# Why a "home" activity will be killed when the home button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I have created an activity , set it's filter as a Home activity  and set `launchMode` with `singleTask`. When I press home ,the activity will be in onpause state then onStop . What confuse me is why the activity will be re-launched when back from icon displayed on "home pick" dialog ? It calls `onCreate()` again without invoked `onDestroy()`.

I know there is a way to solve this problem that is to set `launcherMode` as `singleIstance`, but this way is not good enough, because it will cause an other issue that the activity will not be able to process `onActivityResult`.

Comment: @Darpan ,i wish the activity will not to be killed by home bottom. I found that it happened only once after the app was just installed .

Answer (score 0):

You may want to tell what you wish to achieve. Because that's how `singleTask` is. It delivers existing intent to `onNewIntent()` of the existing instance of activity. So activity will not be destroyed but `onCreate()` will be called, as it will reCreate activity with existing intent.

Quoting the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

Comment: but at this time ,the activity already exists, why need to recreate again?

Comment: because you used the `launchMode= Singletask`. Is it serving some purpose in your app?

Comment: yes,cauz my app is a launcher.. i need to handle the Home event ( by onNewEvent).